# How to segment the flange from the background?

Tags: opencv

I am working on a project, which is to locate a flange using camera system. I have took a photo of this. The main problem is that, the foreground and the background has the same color, almost black. If the background has different color, it will be not so difficult.

I have also tried canny detector, but the detector does not provide good result. The edge is not continous.

Or another methode is to locate such points(in blue), will SIFT or SURF such detector work well?

Anyone could please help me with this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAvpD.jpg)

Comment: Could you add your original input image?

Comment: The link is that input image. "enter image description here"

Answer (score 0):

Template matching would work fine for this. See link:

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

Descriptor based matching such as SIFT, SURF, BRISK etc might not work well since they rely on descriminitive keypoints. For the flange in your question, there will be many points that are very similar which will be discarded in the matching process.

Another technique that would work is the generalized hough transform. It will use edge gradients as opposed to pixel intensity that is used in template matching.

Comment: I also thought about template matching. But later those Points will be transformed into 3d space. Template matching would work also for two images of same object, that are took from different view points? Can the Template matching find the pixel point in two images, that are projected from the same point of object?

Comment: I also thought about template matching. But later those points will be transformed into 3d space. Template matching would work also for two images of same object, that are took from different view points? Can the Template matching find the pixel point in two images, that are projected from the same point of object?            What if I segment the corner by using template matching in some patchs and then use SIFT, SURF detector to find the points?

Comment: Template matching will start to degrade the more drastically the viewpoint changes. However depending on the amount of viewpoint change, you could first use template matching to perform a rough location. Once you have this rough location, use a sub-pixel corner detector in a limited region where you know your corners exist.

Comment: It would be beneficial to know how much change you expect in viewpoint, scale, rotation, aspect etc.

Comment: The change in viewpoint, scale, rotation, aspect is really not big. I think it would be within 5 deg for rotation, 10 deg in viewpoint, etc. I have took many fotos, the flange in my fotos almost look the same. But it still remain a problem, that is illumination and light reflection. Is template matching also a little bit invariant to grey value change? I do not think so.

Comment: Template matching using normalized cross correlation would be invariant to constant (linear) illumination changes, but not to non-linear changes (hot spots etc).